# Trying to tags/hashtags to collection items

Tags: javascript, dom, meteor

Meteor/Javascript n00b here.

I'm trying to add tags or hashtags to bars with the sports teams they support with the intent that the user will be able to filter the bars based on the teams.

I used ajduke:bootstrap-tagsinput and this has gotten me 1/2 way there. I'm able to save the tags to the collection as an array, but how do I used that array to render the tags in the dom?

I imagine a the code would look something like this, but I can't wrap my head around creating something in the DOM from the helper.

```
for(var i=0; i<== tags.length;i++){
  //Code that creates a label or whatever with the tag
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just render the collection of tags using something like (if you happen to be using bootstrap) ...

in your html ...

```
{{#each tags}}
  <div class="badge">{{this}}</div>
{{/each}
```

Comment: Such a simple solution! Thanks so much!!